# Why i'm not getting Ask timeout exception?

Tags: scala, exception, timeout, akka

I have 2 actors one supervisor and a child actor.

The supervisor:

```
class DemoActorSupervisor(implicit val system: ActorSystem, config: Config) extends Actor {

  val childActor: ActorRef = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props[DemoActorChild]), "DemoChildActor")

  context.watch(childActor)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case s: String =>
      childActor forward s
  }
}
```

Child actor:

```
class DemoActorChild extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case s: String =>
      Thread.sleep(100)
      Future.successful(true) pipeTo (sender)
  }
}
```

Main method:

```
object ABC extends App {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Demo")

  implicit val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

  val supervisor = system.actorOf(DemoActorSupervisor.props(), "DemoSupervisor")

  val x: Future[Boolean] = (supervisor ? ("ASK")).mapTo[Boolean]
  x.foreach(println)
}
```

I have set the ask timeout as 5 mili seconds, and doing an ask call to the supervisor actor. which is forwarding the message to the child actor. In the child actor I have put `Thread.sleep(100)` logically I should get the ask timeout exception as I have set timeout to 5 mili seconds and child is taking more than 100 mili second to respond back, but I am not getting ask timeout exception.
can someone tell me what's wrong with the code? How can I get ask timeout exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the description of `Future.foreach`:

> Asynchronously processes the value in the future once the value becomes available.
>
> WARNING: Will not be called if this future is never completed or if it is completed with a failure.

If you want to use `Future.foreach`, you should write something like:

```
x.map(Success(_)).recover({case exception => Failure(exception)}).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```
x.onComplete {
    case Success(v) =>
      println(v)
    case Failure(v) =>
      println(v)
}
```

`Future foreach` just handle success case, `akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException:` belongs to `Failure`, you need to handle it by your code.

Or next also ok:

```
x.foreach(println)
x.failed.foreach(println)
```

Comment: onComplete is working in the failure case if i will right ex.printStackTrace it will print but why foreach is not working like that. why i have to specificly explicitly that it's a failed future or success? Throwable is wraped inside future if i am doing future.foreach so what ever is inside future it should print.

Comment: and what if i don't even do pipeTo sender the result? then what will be the case?